# Writing to file giving unauthorized access in c#

Tags: c#, uwp, streamwriter

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\test1.rtf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
sw.Dispose();
fs.Dispose();
```

This code is giving an unauthorized access error even though I declared the     `<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess"/>`
in the manifest and allowed the app those permissions in privacy setting in Windows 10.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running as the `admin` user?

Comment: Yes, I am the user admin.

Comment: does the file already exist? or are you trying to create and write in the above code?

Comment: Are you trying to run your code in _debug_ from Visual Studio?  If so, make sure that start / run Visual Studio _As Administrator_ to ensure that you have this same level of authorization when you are debugging your code.

Comment: @Daniel the file already exists.

Comment: @DavidTansey running as administrator gives the same issue.

Comment: You should not write to the Documents folder before you declared you can write in the Documents folder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: If you read the my post it says I declared the "broadFileSystemAccess" which should allow writing to anywhere on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have used the [Windows Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR227346) namespace APIs. If you read the document [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations), you would know this point.

> This capability(`broadFileSystemAccess`) works for APIs in the Windows.Storage namespace.

Comment: Got it to work using                 await PathIO.WriteTextAsync("C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\test1.rtf", value);